# How does automatic activity tracking work for google analytics android

Tags: android, android-activity, google-analytics

I've implemented something similar for iOS using a quick swizzle of viewDidAppear to allow my company to track flow around the app in our own internal systems.

Now, ideally I'd like to avoid having to implement appear & disappear tracking in every activity for our internal use, so was hoping someone could shed some light into how the GA library achieves this.

I had a good google around and couldn't find any kind of internal event that's posted when an activity comes into the foreground so am at a bit of a loss at the moment.

Cheers!

Comment: Are you asking how to set up automatic activity tracking, or looking for an explanation as to how automatic activity tracking functions under the hood?

Comment: I'm asking about how they've implemented the feature under the hood

Answer (score 3):

I know the following is not a direct answer to your question but why not applying a basic OOP principle? Inheritance.

```
import android.app.Activity;

public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // hit when activity appears. Tell Appserver!
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // hit when activity hides. Tell Appserver!
    }

}
```

and then have your other Acivities extend this instead of *android.app.Activity*?

Comment: Massive issue with this is when your activities inherit from lots of different base-classes (ListActivity, Activity, FragmentActivity.....)

Comment: I understand that, though it's still an overseeable number of classes. I totally understand that this still isn't an answer to your question, I just have the feeling that searching for a valid answer takes longer than just extending a few classes. Using a halfway decent IDE, it really shouldn't take a whole lot of time. Sure it's not as elegant as decoration or implementable feature or a manager class, or whatever you had in mind, but hey...

Comment: The problem is that I specifically stated that this was not an acceptable solution.. My question was around whether there was any knowledge of any lifecycle events we could use

Comment: I hear you. Did you check Dominik Suszczewiczs answer? I haven't tried it but it looks darn cool.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ActivityLifecycleCallback. Example below:

```
public class MordorApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleLogger());
    }

}


public class ActivityLifecycleLogger implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        createActivityStateLog(activity, "created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
        createActivityStateLog(activity, "started");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        createActivityStateLog(activity, "resumed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
        createActivityStateLog(activity, "paused");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
        createActivityStateLog(activity, "stopped");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {
        createActivityStateLog(activity, "savingStateInstance");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
        createActivityStateLog(activity, "destroyed");
    }

    private void createActivityStateLog(Activity activity, String state) {
        String log = String.format("Activity %s - %s", activity.getClass().getName(), state);
        LOG.debug(log);
    }

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ActivityLifecycleLogger.class);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics has automatic Activity tracking feature.
See 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/?hl=en#analytics-xml

or do John's answer :)
You can create delegate class (suppose `GaUtils`) then call that on resume/pause. Just one line, don't you?

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    GaUtils.onPause(screenName);  // track pause
}
```